# How do I write a sequence of bytes to a serial port in java

Tags: java, serial-port

I am a beginner to java. I have to send 5 consecutive integers to the instument I am working with through the com port. I am using rxtx library. The instrument doesnt respond to my code.  I tried initialising the values to string and then later changed to byte using getbytes. But even this didnt help.It would be a great help if somebody can help me. The instrument is identified at COM5. I tried to first write to the Com port. Data available event is fired. But the inputstream read is unrecognizable characters. I think that the problem is with writing to the port. It would be a great help if somebody can help me.

The serial interface specification of the device is as follow

DIR START CMD VALLO VALHI END

→ 53   1    4    0     83

← 53    1    4    0      83

← 53    27   SLO  SHI    83

A transaction is defined by the following sequence of packets

• → Software sends a request packet.

• ← Instrument sends a response packet.

• ← Instrument sends a status packet.

This represents a single transaction in an entire run.

Each START;CMD; VALLO;VALHI;END above represents a single byte in the packet

```
public class ReadWrite implements SerialPortEventListener {

    OutputStream outputStream;
    InputStream inputStream;
    static SerialPort serialPort;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Enumeration portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        System.out.println("SimpleRead Started.");
        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                System.out.println("Found " + portId.getName());
                if (portId.getName().equals("COM5")) {
                    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleWriteApp", 2000);
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

                    ReadWrite reader = new ReadWrite();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ReadWrite() throws IOException {
        try {
            outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
            inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();

            outputStream.write(53);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.write(1);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.write(4);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.write(0);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.write(83);
            outputStream.flush();

            System.out.println("The port in use is " + serialPort);

            System.out.println("write done");

            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    }

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

        switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case SerialPortEvent.BI:
            System.out.println("The serial port event is BI ");

        case SerialPortEvent.OE:

        case SerialPortEvent.FE:

        case SerialPortEvent.PE:

        case SerialPortEvent.CD:

        case SerialPortEvent.CTS:

        case SerialPortEvent.DSR:

        case SerialPortEvent.RI:

        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
            System.out.println("The serial port event is OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY ");
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

            System.out.println("The serial port event is Data available ");
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];
            System.out.println(event.getEventType());
            try {
                while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                    System.out.print(new String(readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "us-ascii"));
                }
                System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            serialPort.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your entire Java code so we can help you?

Comment: It's really difficult to debug without knowing about your instrument. But did you `flush()` the outputstream after writing and check?

Comment: There's not enough code to see why it's not doing what you expect it to. What you have written above should indeed write 5 bytes to some outputstream, but it's impossible from the snippet to tell if you've actually opened a serial port and if you're listening for data from it.

Comment: i have included the entire code now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of the reading part.  I had to convert the string to byte array using getBytes since there is a stream of bytes coming from the module. Then I print it one by one

```
     public class TwoWaySerialComm {

     void connect( String portName ) throws Exception {
     CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier
      .getPortIdentifier( portName );
        if( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() ) {
  System.out.println( "Error: Port is currently in use" );
   } else {
  int timeout = 10000;
  CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open( this.getClass().getName(), timeout );

  if( commPort instanceof SerialPort ) {
    SerialPort serialPort = ( SerialPort )commPort;
    serialPort.setSerialPortParams( 38400,
                                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE );

    InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
    OutputStream outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write( 53 ); 
    outputStream.write( 1 ); 
    outputStream.write( 20 ); 
    outputStream.write( 0 ); 
    outputStream.write( 83 ); 




    CommPort port = serialPort;
    System.out.println( "Write done" );
    ( new Thread( new SerialReader( in,port  ) ) ).start();


  } else {
    System.out.println( "Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example." );
  }
}
  }


  public static class SerialReader implements Runnable {

    InputStream in;
    CommPort serialport;
    public SerialReader( InputStream in, CommPort port) {
      this.in = in;
      serialport = port;
    }

    public void run() {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
      int len = -1;

      try {
        while( ( len = this.in.read( buffer ) ) > -1 ) {

            String stringis= new String( buffer, 0, len,"ASCII" );
         //System.out.println( stringis );
         byte[] by_new = stringis.getBytes();
         System.out.println("the lenghth of byte array is "+ by_new.length);
         System.out.println( "The read is " );
         for(int i=0; i<by_new.length; i++) 

            System.out.printf( "%5s",by_new[i]);

         serialport.close();

        }
      } catch( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    }
    }



  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    try {
      ( new TwoWaySerialComm() ).connect( "COM2" );

    } catch( Exception e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```